# Maximum likelihood estimation when the density is $f(x;\theta) = \theta x^{\theta -1} $

Tags: statistics

Working through this given problem on maximum likelihood estimation (MLE). The density is given as

$$f(x;\theta) = \theta x^{\theta -1} $$
transforming the above equation to MLE, we have

$$L(x;\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \theta x^{\theta - 1} $$

then we have
$$L(x;\theta) = {\theta}^n \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{\theta - 1}. $$
Taking $\ln$
$$
\begin{align}
\ln L(x;\theta) &= \ln{\theta}^n \ln\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{\theta - 1}\\
&=n\ln{\theta} ({\theta - 1})\ln\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\\
&=n\ln{\theta} ({\theta - 1})\ln\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}.
\end{align}
$$
Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ is what is turning me off here, or is there any thing i have done wrongly.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Probably you should replace some of your $x$ with $x_i$, and also review  your algebra, which is terribly wrong!

Comment: pls tell me where the mistakes lie

Comment: OK, in your third dispalyed equation line, it suddenly appears a summation sign, which really should be a product line, as in the displayed equation above it!

Comment: to remove the product sign, it transform to that.

Comment: What do you mean by "it transforsm to that"? It transforms to that, yes, when you take logarithms, but you didnt take logarithms, yet!

Comment: pls sorry to bother you, can u give me the right thing?

Comment: Is it a question from a book?

Answer (score 3):

OK, but you have a lot to learn. First, you did not specify your problem completely: you did not specify the ranges of $x$ and $\theta$, without which you cannot really advance! I interpret your question as being about a special case of the Pareto distribution, which specify's that $x>1$ and $\alpha >0$. (I change notation a bit here!). Then the density is given by
$$
    f(x, \alpha) = \alpha x^{-\alpha-1}
$$
which you can check is non-negative and integrates to one.

Then, you didn't specify you have $n$ independent observations, but your wrong algebra seems to assume that, so I will assume it.

Now, write the likelihood function based on $n$ independent observations, and the notation $(x_1, \dots, x_n)=x$.
$$
   L(\alpha) = \prod_{i=1}^n \alpha x_i^{-\alpha-1}
   =  \alpha^n \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{-\alpha-1}
$$
Now, let us take the logarithm, so passing to the loglikelihood function:
$$
   \log L(\alpha) = n\log(\alpha) + \sum_{i=1}^n (-\alpha-1) \log(x_i)
$$
which we can simplify as
$$
    n\log(\alpha) + (-\alpha-1) \sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)
$$
which is much simpler (and correct!) than you got. Now you should be able to find the maximum yourself.

Comment: thank you. could be that there was mistake in my problem definition.

Comment: You went from product to sum _before_ taking logs.